# What are the $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$-invariant Baire measures on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, group-actions

This was an interesting problem that came up in qual studying.

$SL(2, \mathbb{R})$ acts on $\mathbb{R}^2$, and hence on any measure on $\mathbb{R}^2$. What are the Baire measures (i.e. Borel measures finite on compact sets) that are invariant under this action?

Two obvious ones are the Lebesgue measure, and delta masses at the origin. I suspect that there are none which are not a linear combination of these. Intuitively, it seems like if we can find some set which has very small Lebesgue measure, then we should be able to squeeze many $SL(2, \mathbb{R})$-orbits of it into a compact set, but I haven't been able to formalize this.

Comment: Hmm. Intuitively it seems that if a locally compact topological group $G$ acts transitively on a locally compact space $X$, then there should be (up to scaling) a unique invariant Baire measure on $X$. Is that a theorem?

Comment: Consider two such measures $\mu$ and $\nu$.  We can assume (replacing $\mu$ with $\mu + \nu$ if necessary) that $\nu$ is absolutely continuous wrt $\mu$, so $\nu(dx) = h(x) \mu(dx)$ where $h(x)$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative.  By uniqueness of the Radon-Nikodym derivative, the function $h$ is ($\mu$-almost everywhere) invariant under $G$.  But if $G$ is transitive, that says $h$ is $\mu$-almost everywhere constant.